# Dismiss makes jump a view controller Swift

Tags: ios, segue, dismiss

I have four VCs

1. `main`,
2. `shopVC`,
3. `itemCategories`,
4. `productDetails`

and they're all connected in sequence.

> main -> ShopVC -> itemCategories -> productDetails

When dismissing `productDetails` I increment a `dismissCounter`, so in `itemCategories's` `viewWillAppear` I check `dismissCounter` and if is not `0` it will also dismiss and goes back to `shopVc`.

It all works as expected if I have set a segue `chooseProductCategorySegue` from `shopVc` to `itemCategories`  as **`present modally.`**

If I instead have this **segue** as **`show`** to include the navigation back button in `itemCategories`, then it directly dismisses to `main` instead of `shopVC`. What can be causing this?

I'm thinking that using an `unwind` segue from all VCs instead of dismissing them would be an option.
Many thanks for your help as always.

Comment: where is your  dismissCounter present, how are you sharing value of dismissCounter across all 4 ViewControllers?

Comment: Not sure how your architecture is set and where you're calling the dismiss, but be sure to know that you should use `UIViewController.dismiss(animated: completion:)` to dismiss a view controller that was presented on top of another VC. To dismiss a VC that was pushed to a navigation controller, you should use `UINavigationController.popViewController(animated:)`

Comment: @SaurabhYadav I increment stati variable `GlobalVariabiles.dismissCounter` from `productDetails`.

Comment: @pepsy thanks. I'm never sure about dismissing VCs..
So I changed it all together and added an `unwind` to `shopVC` and from `itemDetailsVC` I just unwind to `shopVC`. Easier, faster and cleaner. No more dismiss counters..

Comment: But to understand it better, let me ask you. When you perform `chooseProductCategorySegue` as `show` is considered push, so dismissing `itemCategories` with `dismiss(animated:)` is the proper way. But that actually wasn't working properly as in `shopVC` there is no `dismiss(animated:)`, but dismissing `itemCategories` would jump to `main`. `itemCategories` was dismissing properly dough, if `chooseProductCategorySegue` was `Present Modally`.

Comment: @Vincenzo I hardly ever use segues, so I'm not sure how to answer. I just mentioned about popping a VC from a navigation controller because I thought you could be using a UINavigationController, and dismissing it entirely instead of popping one of its view controllers.

Comment: @pepsy sure, I'm using a navigation controller. Is it the reason for the jump you think? Well I'll dig into it but so far using the unwind segue instead of dismiss allows me to keep the back button. Thank you for helping out.